# Writing a C program in order to removing occurrance from a text file including a symbol

Tags: c

I have a **text file** with a pattern like :

```
1,2,3$
2,4,1,5,6$
3,1,2,9$
1,0,9,8,7,3$
3,8,2,9$
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

and I have a `char new[]="3,1,2,9$"`

I need a C-function in order to check if the text file mentioned above contains `char new[]="3,1,2,9$"` or not.

This is my code but it doesn't work:

```
int main(void)
{
    char new[100]="0,1268,1236$";
    FILE *my_file;
    char string[2000];
    int ind=0;
    int rest;
    int found = 0;

    my_file=fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while((string[ind++]=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(string[ind]='$')
        {
            rest=strcmp(string,new);
            if(rest==0)
            {
                found =1;
                printf("found");
                ind=0;
            }
            strcpy(string, "");
        }
    }
    fclose(my_file);
}
```

Can someone please point out my mistakes or let me know of a better solution?

Comment: "This is my code but it doesn't work" - sigh.

Comment: You could use `strstr` instead of the manual search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the file. But, you don't seem to reading anything from it at all.

The `getchar()` seems to be reading from the console or you haven't posted the code correctly.

Please use `fgets` or `fread` to read data from the file and then do the comparison.